# Error on line 16 when using select from database

Tags: php

Its ok i fixed it now no further help is required. Thanks for all your help in trying to fix it for me though its muchly appreciated :)

Comment: Please add the error to the question. You also should use the error reporting function after the query execution.

Comment: As @user3783243 said please tell us the error. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: this is what its giving   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /storage/ssd4/320/6910320 on line 16

Comment: Do you have a table named "MyGuests"..?

Comment: @Chukwuemeka Inya no that code above is an example of the type im using its all linked correctly because the default unlinked banner comes up but the linkable one wont im trying to get it to select 4 most recent banners

Comment: Oh....You should pls show us your real code. The only thing you should hide is your credentials.

Comment: `var_dump($result)` gives what? Does http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php give any useful errors?

Comment: Its ok i sorted it now i had a working copy on my memory stick thank goodness and it works thanks anyway guys for all your help in trying to fix it  ☺ much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think i know your problem. Your query doesn't give you number as the result, the query give you object.
You should give query `count`

```
Select count id, firstname, lastname from MyGuest
```

The error in line 16 occur because you compare object with integer.

And after you already execute the query, change the if syntax with this

```
If($result>0)
```

Comment: $results is a mixed return value: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php it normally returns an object you can use `num_rows`

Answer (score -1):

try putting an `if` around the query:

```
if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
    $result->close();
}
```

and check if your query is correct (fields are spelled correctly, table name is right,...): eg. put it into `phpmyadmin` and see if there is any error.

Comment: Thanks i'll give it ago

Comment: it didn't work but thanks anyways its saying its to do with the if on line 16 > if ($result->num_rows > 0) { its colored kinda purple if, while and else are all purple color and when i add that code you give above it tells me if, echo, while and else are wrong

Comment: it normally does this because $result is not a correct object because the query results in an error. That's what I hoped to compensate through the if around it